# Separately changing colours for each heading under h3

Tags: html, css

I am learning how to use html and css, I have 4 headings that are under h3, the first 2 text on h3 I want to be orange and the 2 headings text at the bottom which are also under h3 I want to turn green.

Can anyone help please

Comment: You should post what code you have so far. Have you googled this at all?

Comment: [Why is can someone help me not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Yes I have but I am unable to find what I’m looking for. I have put the put the code p{ color; orange and it has coloured  all 4 of my headings that color but I want the other 2 green

Comment: Please inlclude your HTML in the question with your best attempt with CSS. It is easier for us to help you with a [MCVE]

Comment: Is there away that I can split the paragraphs like you can on python

Comment: What? Paragraphs? Where has that come from? We were talking `hx` heading tags. Please show your code. Give us something to work with and some important context.

Comment: <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style>


h3{ color: orange;bn
  }

Comment: I am trying to get these 2 heading which are also under h3 green ---- The first Programmer

Ada Lovelace was an English mathematician and writer, chiefly known for her 

The first Compiler

Grace Hopper was an America

Comment: We're getting there..... but edit (https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54757499/edit) the question instead of adding comments. Then use the `<>` in the button to add an interactive snippet.

Comment: Please see my questions in a comment to my answer. We really need to see this code. If you respond to my questions, I will try to help you get your code into your question.

Comment: I'm trying to write down the code but its saying I'm doing the wrong format on the message..   Jon I'm appreciate your help buddy, when you say you need the html. what does that mean please is their any way you can give it to me I layman terms please

Comment: OK, lets try one more thing. Try adding your code to https://codepen.io/pen/ or https://jsfiddle.net/ . Then save it and share the link here. I will then edit the code into the question. You can bring the comment to my attention with @[My user name]. Once you type "@J" You should get a pop up with my user name.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use CSS pseudo nth-child selectors. You can directly specify the h3 you want by using it's child index. The first H3 is 1, second H3 is 2, etc.

```css
h3:nth-child(1) {
  color: orange;
}

h3:nth-child(2) {
  color: orange;
}

h3:nth-child(3) {
  color: green;
}

h3:nth-child(4) {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<h3>Header 1</h3>
<h3>Header 2</h3>
<h3>Header 3</h3>
<h3>Header 4</h3>
```

Comment: I have just put the child codes for h3 child 3 & 4 but it turn it all back to the default colour.... should I take away my original code for h3 and do them all separately as the example Michael gave me

Comment: @JermaineRobinson Please include your code, particularly the HTML, in the question itself. Use https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54757499/edit  to edit the question. We are guessing without the code.

Comment: Jon there are 4 headings 1 at the start of each paragraph. I have use the code h3{ colour: orange;} which has changed all 4 to orange

Comment: We really need to see how your HTML is marked up in order to say specifically what you have to do

Answer (score 0):

[nth-last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child) is the selector you want

```css
/*Default color;*/
.someheadings h3 {
  color: orange;
}


/*Color the last 2;*/
.someheadings h3:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="someheadings">
  <h3>I'm Orange</h3>
  <h3>I'm also Orange</h3>
  <h3>I'm green</h3>
  <h3>I'm also green</h3>
</div>
```

The syntax for `nth-child` and `nth-last-child` can get a little weird. The following article give a good indication of what you can do: https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/

I'll reiterate my previous comment, in the future **help us help you** by including code in your question so we don't have to guess your HTML or what you have tried so far.

Comment: I'm trying to copy and paste whats on my screen to give you what code I have put in but its saying I'm entering the code incorrectly.. sorry Jon I am very new to this

Comment: No problem....we'll try to get you there. Have you managed to get your question into "Edit Mode"?  Have you managed to active "Snippets" (The `<>` button or *ctrl-m*)?

Comment: [This article](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) is a little old, the button is different now, but it might help get you a snippet into your question.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer, thanks for all the help peeps, your help was very much appreciated.

All I had to do was change the h3 to h4 on the two other headings then do the rest

h4 [ color: green:}..

it reminded me of life . so simple